# SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: certificate, git

Behind a firewall, using chrome, I am able to access a github repository like so:
https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Chrome uses our certificate for this access. If I try to access the same url using [GitExtensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/), I get this error:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Can I cause GitExtensions to use our certificate to allow access?

EDIT: more info:

On my machine, I don’t see mysysGit, but I do see mingw/curl, so I assume Git is using these. These apparently do not use Windows trust certificates when building the certificate chain. The error that I get, S*SL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain*,  indicates that the root certificate used by Git/Github is not present in the built-in certificate authority (CA) root bundle.  As @Akber Choudhry has pointed out, the CA certificate that is the root of the chain of the certs served by Github SSL server is  **DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA** and I do see that CA in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt.

To verify that the problem is with Git, not GitExtensions, I did this on the command line:

```
 >>git clone https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows.git
```

And received the same SSL certificate problem error.

It gives the appearance that Git is not using this certificate, thus I tried configuring Git like so:

```
>>git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

but this had no effect..

Comment: What certificate is actually being used? what location are you connecting to? and are you 100% sure your not getting MitM'ed?

Comment: We are not getting MitM'ed. I'm not the network guy here, but I do believe the certificate is one that has been purchased. I don't know what you mean when you ask what location is being connected to.

Comment: talk to the network guy first, than check your TLS server setup (you can use tools like [ssllabs.com], and learn about how the HTTP(s) protocol actually work . because you assume way to much, and you need to know stuff not assume them.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out GitKraken. I use it for my development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Behind a firewall, ...github ... Chrome uses our certificate for this access.

Based on this description I assume that "our" certificate is not the original certificate for Github but that you are using a firewall with SSL inspection which generates its own ("our") certificate to a man in the middle the connection. The CA in the firewall which issued this certificate (proxy CA) is probably added to the Windows Trust Store and this Chrome will trust it.

But Git doesn't use the Windows Trust Store and thus doesn't know about this proxy CA. Therefore you need to add the proxy CA used by the firewall to the CA store for the Git and not the original CA which issued the 
certificate for Github.

Comment: I ended up to [doing this] which is: 1. make copy of curl-ca-bundle.crt. 2. Copy/paste the `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` into this copy. 3. Point Git to this copy.

Answer (score 1):

When you use chrome and access Github over HTTPS, you are just verifying Github's certificate chain against built-in root certs in your browser and in Windows.

Under the covers, Gitextensions uses msysgit, which does not consult Windows trust certificates when building the certificate chain.

From the error, it appears that the root certificate used by Github is not present in the built-in certificate authority (CA) root bundle.  This may just be due to Gitextensions bundling an older version of msysgit or curl.

msysgit does include `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` in its CA bundle and it has been there for a number of years. Search for this string in the file `bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

Check if there is an older version of msysgit or mingw tools installed on your machine. If so, clean out and re-install. Finally, consult msysgit certificate addition procedure if you need to add the certificate.

Comment: Looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt, I do see that CA.

Comment: Is [mysysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) obsolete? It says at that page that msysGit has been superseded by Git for Windows 2.x. Also, I don't understand how that particular CA (DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA) is significant. Can you explain?

Comment: That CA certificate is the root of the chain of the certs served by github SSL server. If your client (browser or git client) has that root certificate defined, it can validate the origin of the other certificates in the chain.  I am not sure where it is picking up the CA bundle from but try wiping it out and installing Git for Windows.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by "wiping it out"? i..e what is "it" and how to I wipe it out?

Comment: It would depend on your system and path and from where curl gets invoked.  I would say that any mingw or msysgit installations should go.

Comment: I searched the entire hard drive for "mysysGit" and found nothing. There is mingw, at **C:\Program Files\Git\ mingw64\** which contains, among many folder and files, \bin\curl.exe

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that Gitextensions is not using HTTPS as the protocol, maybe client-side SSH?. Does Git for Windows work with HTTPS?